# ElasticSearch 2.X finding a numeric value exists in the array fails

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-dsl

I have mapping of one filed is as follows in ES2.3

```
"move_in_ts": {
  "type": "integer"
}

"move_out_ts": {
  "type": "integer"
}

Sample document stores data as follows:

"move_in_ts": [
        1475280000,
        1475539200,
        1475712000,
        1475884800,
        1477008000,
        1477785600
      ]
```

I have a script in my DSL query (trying to find an integer in that array)

```
"script": "if(doc['move_in_ts'] && doc['move_in_ts'].values.contains('1475280000')){return 200;}"
```

and also tried this:

```
 "script": "if(doc['move_in_ts'] && doc['move_in_ts'].contains('1475280000')){return 200;}"
```

and also tried this:

```
 "script": "if(doc['move_in_ts'] && doc['move_in_ts'].contains(1475280000)){return 200;}"
```

and also tried this:

```
 "script": "if(doc['move_in_ts'] && doc['move_in_ts'].values.contains(1475280000)){return 200;}"
```

but in all above cases, I get the following error:

```
"reason": {
      "type": "null_pointer_exception",
      "reason": null
    }
```

It might be possible that this field doesn't exist at all in few documents (I cannot use filter in my use case, I need to have it in the script only)

What am I doing wrong or how to get it work?

Comment: is 'move_in_ts' nested field?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. Could you post your whole query? Is your index huge?

Comment: no it is not a nested field

Comment: @ChintanShah25 no my index is pretty tiny. Which particular script worked for you?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 this is my real script that I am using. `"functions": [{
            "script_score": {
              "script": "if (doc['move_in_ts'] && doc['move_out_ts']) {return per_day_boost * ( [ doc['move_in_ts'], doc['move_out_ts'] ].transpose().find { av_start, av_out -> av_start <= desired_in_ts && av_out >= desired_out_ts }[0] - desired_in_ts).abs()/86400}; return 0;",
              "params": {
                "per_day_boost": -175,
                "desired_in_ts": 1478131200,
                "desired_out_ts": 1494547200
              }
            }
          }]`

Comment: and my real script throws this error `"reason": "failed to run inline script [if (doc['move_in_ts'] && doc['move_out_ts']) {return per_day_boost * ( [ doc['move_in_ts'], doc['move_out_ts'] ].transpose().find { av_start, av_out -> av_start <= desired_in_ts && av_out >= desired_out_ts }[0] - desired_in_ts).abs()/86400}; return 0;] using lang [groovy]",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object"
          }` I simplified my question at stackoverflow to get first level work

Comment: ohh, this is a big script. Did you find anything in ES logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127201/discussion-between-chintanshah25-and-jvk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the issue(I am also using ES 2.3). You would also need `toLong()` to get the right results or it will give zero results. I created sample index like this.

```
PUT books
{
  "mappings": {
    "book":{
      "properties": {
        "move_in_ts":{
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I indexed few docs

```
POST books/book
{
  "move_in_ts" : null
}

POST books/book
{
  "move_in_ts" : [4,null]
}

POST books/book
{
  "move_in_ts" : []
}

POST books/book
{
  "some_other_field" : "some value"
}

POST books/book
{
  "move_in_ts" : [
        1475280000,
        1475539200,
        1475712000,
        1475884800,
        1477008000,
        1477785600
      ]
}
```

Then below query gives right result

```
GET books/book/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "if(doc['move_in_ts'] && doc['move_in_ts'].values.contains(1475280000.toLong())){return 200;}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```